# How do I prevent a javascript from reloading every time a button is click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, html

I have this script which shows a message to the user when the page is loaded in ASP.NET, my problem is that every time an user clicks any button which causes I believe a PostBack the same message gets reloaded. I only want to show this on First Page load. Any help will be appreciate.

```
$('.block .message').hide().append('<span class="close" title="Dismiss"></span>').fadeIn('slow');
$('.block .message .close').hover(
    function () { $(this).addClass('hover'); },
    function () { $(this).removeClass('hover'); }
);

$('.block .message .close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

Here is my HTML code,

```
<div class="message info">The first input field would allow you to provide the From Date, PO, Shipment or Single Date.</div>
```

Comment: That hover code is certainly not needed. Simply use the `:hover` pseudo-class instead of the `.hover` class...

Comment: You just need to not show it if it is already visible.

Comment: So, is the question "How do I make ASP.NET not do a full page reload every time a button is clicked?" or "How do I make my JS detect the difference between the initial load and a postback load?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add runat=server and an id:

```
<div class="message info" runat="server" id="divmessage" >
```

Add code in your Page_Load to make it visible only if !IsPostback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   divmessage.visible = !IsPostBack;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add this to your page:

```
<script>
    function isPostBack () {
      return <%= Page.IsPostBack %>;
    }
</script>
```

And now:

```
if ( !isPostBack() ) {
    //show message
}
```